# Yii AR. Непонятное поведение атрибута модели.

Tags: model, ar, yii, json, php

Привет всем!
У меня в БД Postgres есть таблица tasks, во фреймворке Yii она представлена моделью Task. ОПри создании новых записей в этой таблице, в одно из полей записывается содержимое в формате json. Там небольшие структуры данных, и Я пока решил не заморачиваться с кучей мелких таблиц.

В общем, когда создаю новую запись путем создания инстанса модели, и присвоения  атрибутам модели, в БД запись создается корректно, но когда получаю данные из БД, поле модели, в котором лежит json объект почему-то имеет значение:

```
'command_data' =>
    string(2) "[]"
```

Откуда эти скобки квадратные? Что за магия происходит? beforeSave(), и afterSave() в модели не переопределены.

**=== UPD**
Если выполнить такой код:

```
$res = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT command_data FROM tasks")->queryAll();
var_dump($res);
```

Результат будет вот такой:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'command_data' =>
    string(2) "[]"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'command_data' =>
    string(2) "[]"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    'command_data' =>
    string(2) "[]"
  }
}
```

**=== UPD**

Мужики! Вопрос решен! **Я невнимательный идиот!** Проблема была в том, что Я код получения модели выполнял путем запуска консольной команды, и вот в конфиге для командной строки у меня настройки подключения к БД были совершенно другие!

Comment: Странно, можете показать пример строки из базы и код с помощью которого вы сохраняете данные.

Comment: Какой тип поля в БД?

Comment: @artkill, Тип поля character varying(4096). Длина json -объекта в моем случае менее 600 символов.

@Kison, вот значение поля:
{"server":{"guid":"6cb6221b-3514-4096-a321-881090fd27ce","is_installed":0,"account_id":37,"platform_id":1,"host_server_id":1,"address":"192.168.1.116","port_id":21,"login":"mylogin","password":"mypassword","id":"52","keyfile":null,"hash":null,"is_online":null,"is_freeze":null,"is_blocked":null,"is_reserved":null,"date_created":null}}

Comment: @Kison, соххраняю вот так:

            $t->command_data = CJSON::encode(array(
                        'server' => $server->attributes,
            ));
            if ($t->validate())
            {
                $t->save();
            }